# Can this expression be made true ? 2 _ _ _ _ = 2015

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Make this expression true:  2 _ _ _ _= 2015
The underscores must be replaced by any 2 of of the operational symbols +, - , x, / (divide). And any 2 of the digits 0,1,2..9.

So, you basically need 2 operational symbols and 2 digits (digits and operational symbols can be repeated).

I have been stuck on this math puzzle for almost a week now and have tried numerous arrangements of the symbols and digits but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. I am now beginning to believe that there is actually no solution. How would I go about proving this?

Thank you :)

Comment: I can't see how you'd get higher than $2\times 9 \times 9 = 162$ swapping either a digit or an operation would result in a smaller number.  Are you allowing powers? Normal precedence for operations? I'm missing something but can't put my finger  on it.

Comment: Hi @anonymous: Can you made true the "equality" $VII=I$  just moving a  phosphor of the five ones here? (lack both the equal sign).

Comment: If a unary + symbol is allowed, then you can get up to $2\times+99=198$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that two operational symbols have to exist in the red places : 
$$2\color{red}{\circ}\circ\color{red}{\circ}\circ=2015.$$
Then, we have
$$\text{LHS}\le 2\times 9\times 9=162\lt 2015.$$

Comment: I thought I was missing something. +1

Comment: Digits can be placed in the red places as well. For example, if I put 3 in the first red place, it would make the number 23.

Comment: @anonymous: When you put 3 in the first red place, where do you put two operational symbols?

Comment: Oh I see now never realised that was allowed.

Comment: You could put - - which becomes +.

Comment: @anonymous: Do you mean that two operational symbols can be next to each other??

Comment: Yes, but only + - and - -.

Comment: Wait. I don't believe that will make any difference to the solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Mathlove:  can you draw a square with three straight line segments?